# How to find/grep what is between string1 and string2?

Tags: text-processing, grep

I am trying to extract a value from a long string that may change over time. So for example the string could look something like this

```
....../filename-1.9.0.3.tar.gz"<....
```

And what I want to extract is the value between **filename-** and **.tar.gz**, essentially the file version (1.9.0.3 in this case). The reason I need to do it this way is because I may later run the command and the value will be 1.9.0.6 or 2.0.0.2 or something entirely different.

How can I do this? I'm currently only using grep, but I wouldn't mind using other utilities such as sed or awk or cut or whatever. To be perfectly clear, I need to extract only the file version part of the string, since it is very long (on both sides) everything else needs to be cut out somehow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `grep -P`/`pcregrep`, using a positive look-behind and a positive look-ahead:

```
grep -P -o '(?<=STRING1).*?(?=STRING2)' infile
```

in your case replace `STRING1` with `filename-` and `STRING2` with `\.tar\.gz`

---

If you don't have access to `pcregrep` and/or if your `grep` doesn't support `-P` you can do this with your favourite text processing tool. Here's a portable way with `ed` that gives you the same output:

```
ed -s infile <<\IN
g/STRING1/s//\ 
&/g
v/STRING1.*STRING2/d
,s/STRING1//
,s/STRING2.*//
,p
IN
```

How it works: a newline is prepended to each `STRING1` occurrence (so now there's at most one occurrence per line) then all lines not matching `STRING1.*STRING2` are deleted; on the remaining ones we only keep what's between `STRING1` and `STRING2` and print the result.

Comment: If I am grepping a file, where do I put the name of that file?

Comment: Or `grep -P -o 'filename-\K.*?(?=\.tar\.gz)'` (with recent enough versions of PCRE). `.*?` would be better than `.*` if there may be more than one `.tar.gz` per line.

Comment: This works perfectly for me, marking as answer. But as one final thing, how do I make it so that only one of the results is displayed (i.e. right now I am getting two results because there are two instances of this string) can I do that with just grep? Or will I need to use another program (like **head -1**)?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - thanks ! @Cestarian - use `grep -P -om1 ...` to stop at first match

Comment: Note that `grep -Pom1` will print _all_ the matches of the first matching line. `echo abc | grep -Pom1 .` will print `a`, `b` and `c` lines. `pcregrep` doesn't support `-m`, but supports `pcregrep -o1 'filename-(.*?)\.tar\.gz'` and `pcregrep -Mo1 '(?s)filename-(.*?)\.tar\.gz.*'`

Answer (score 2):

For the benefit of people without `grep -P`, you can do this with `sed` or `awk` on any POSIX system.

```
sed -n -e 's/^.*\/filename-\([^\/]*\)\.tar\.gz.*$/\1/p' -e T -e q
```

Explanation: turn off default printing, find a line containing the desired pattern and substitute everything away except the part you want to keep, print the result of the substitution, and exit if there was a match. Note that if there are multiple matches on the first matching line, this picks up the last one.

With awk (picking the first match on the line):

```
awk 'match($0, /filename-[^/]*\.tar\.gz/) {
    print substr(RSTART + 9, RSTART + RLENGTH - 9 - 6, $0);
    exit;
}'
```