# How do I display all the characters between two specific strings?

Tags: shell, shell-script

I want to display all the characters in a file between strings "xxx" and "yyy" (the quotes are not part of the delimiters). How can I do that ? For example, if i have input "Hello world xxx this is a file yyy", the output should be " this is a file "

Comment: Are xxx and yyy always on the same line?

Comment: No they are not

Comment: It's very similar to [How to find/grep what is between string1 and string2?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/266904) so if you want to match multi-line you could run: `pcregrep -Mo '(?<=STRING1)(\n|.)*?(?=STRING2)' infile`

Comment: What yyy would be your xxx expected output xxx if this line yyy were used yyy as input?  In general, the answer to this question is ["regular expressions"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/5419599) but there are some details you haven't thought about.

Comment: So the strings are not on the same line but you accept an answer that only works if they are on the same line (and even then...) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the pattern matching flag in `sed` as follows:

```
echo "Hello world xxx this is a file yyy" | sed 's/.*xxx \(.*\)yyy/\1/'
```

So `.*xxx` will match from the beginning up to `xxx`. This is best shown using `grep`:

[image]

`\1` is a 'Remember pattern' that remembers everything that is within `\(.*\)` so from `xxx` up to `yyy` but not `yyy`.

Finally the remembered string is printed.

Comment: It would be better to use `grep -o '.*xxx'` than a screenshot.

Answer (score 4):

This should do what you are trying to do :

```
sed -e 's/xxx\(.*\)yyy/\1/'
```

This assumes both delimiter strings are on the same line

Comment: What if the delimiters are not on the same line ?

Comment: Also can you explain to me the line you wrote ?

Comment: It uses substitution. It finds the string inclusive of `xxx` and `yyy`. The `\(.*\)` construct matches anything in between the delimiters (callled remembered pattern) and replaces it with the first remembered pattern denoted by `\1`(sed can facilitate up to 9 remembered patterns).

Comment: The two sed solutions do not handle the case where the tags are on separate lines (because sed works on one line at a time).  That *could* be done with a (fairly) complicated sed script, but other tools are more suited to this.

Answer (score 2):

The question is only interesting if the delimiters are not necessarily on the same line.  It can be done several ways (even with `sed`), but `awk` is more flexible:

```
    #!/bin/sh
    awk '
    BEGIN { found = 0; }
    /xxx/ {
        if (!found) {
            found = 1;
            $0 = substr($0, index($0, "xxx") + 3);
        }
    }
    /yyy/ {
        if (found) {
            found = 2;
            $0 = substr($0, 0, index($0, "yyy") - 1);
        }
    }   
        { if (found) {
            print;
            if (found == 2)
                found = 0;
        }
    }
    '
```

This is tested lightly for the cases where at most one substring is on a line, using this data:

```
    this is xxx yy
    first
    second yyy

    xxx.x
    yyy

    xxx#yyy
```

and this output (script is "foo", data is "foo.in"):

```
    $ cat foo.in|./foo
     yy
    first
    second 
    .x

    #
```

The way it works, is that the input data is in `$0`, and awk matches the patterns `xxx` and `yyy` in sequence, allowing more than one thing to change `$0` on its way to the last step, where it is printed.

By the way, this example would not work for

```
xxxxHelloyyyxxxWorldyyy
```

since it checks only the first match.  The Perl script will give different results, since it uses a greedy match rather than the index/substr which I used in the awk example.  Perl, of course, can do the same -- with a script.

Awk (like Perl) is free-format, so one could express the command as something like

```
awk 'BEGIN{found=0;}/xxx/{if(!found){found=1;$0=substr($0,index($0, "xxx")+3);}}/yyy/{if(found){found=2;$0=substr($0,0,index($0,"yyy")-1);}}{ if(found){print;if(found==2)found=0;}}'
```

but that is rarely done, except for the sake of example.  Likewise, `sed` scripts (line-oriented), can be combined into a single line with some restrictions.  Again, complex scripts in `sed` are rarely dealt with in that manner.  Rather, they are treated like real programs (see [example](http://ncurses.scripts.mit.edu/?p=ncurses.git;a=blob;f=man/manlinks.sed;h=78055b4c7c7dc217e6bb6670e5567bb45f7a10a7;hb=HEAD)).

Further reading:

- [AWK Language Programming](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_toc.html), Edition 1.0
- [mawk - pattern scanning and text processing language](http://invisible-island.net/mawk/manpage/mawk.html)
- [Unix Sed Tutorial: 6 Examples for Sed Branching Operation](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/12/unix-sed-tutorial-6-examples-for-sed-branching-operation/)

Comment: Since I'm the only one who used perl, I guess you're referring to my solution. And yes, that too fails horribly on your last example.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with python :

```
import sys
import re
F=open(sys.argv[1])
text=F.read()
reg=re.compile("xxx((?:.|\n)*)yyy")
for match in reg.finditer(text):
    print match.groups()[0]
```

Save this script as a file "post.py" and launch it with:

python post.py your_file_to_search_in.txt

The script compiles a regular expression and print all occurences found in the text of the file.

(?:.|\n) is a non capturing group matching any character including newline

Edit : solution improved thanks to 1_CR tips :

```
import sys
import re
F=open(sys.argv[1])
text=F.read()
reg=re.compile(r'xxx(.*)yyy',re.DOTALL)
for match in reg.finditer(text):
    print match.groups()[0]
```

Comment: Just pass `re.DOTALL` to avoid having to specify `\n` separately. Place `xxx` in look behind assertion and `yyy` in look ahead assertion since OP only needs the text in between these two. Lastly, as good practice always raw-string your regexes

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I've edited my answer to take into account except the lookbehind and lookahead part. My grouping parenthesis dont include xxx nor yyy so OP will only have the text between these two.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that also works when `xxx`and `yyy` is not on the same line:

`cat /tmp/xxx-to-yyy| perl -ne '(/xxx/../yyy/) && print' | perl -pe 's/.*(xxx.*)/$1/' | perl -pe 's/(.*yyy).*/$1/'`

Not exactly pretty...

The `-e` switch to `perl` is just to give the script on the command line.
The `-n` and `-p` makes it loop over the input lines, with `-p` they are printed after the script, with `-n` they aren't. So basically this just sends the file through three perl loops.

`..` is a range operator, that returns false until the left condition returns true, and false after the right condition returns true, so the first loop cut down the file to the lines between the two strings (both included. The last two perl commands remove the text before `xxx` and after `yyy`.