# How to find characters between 2 strings and append them with some text to end of line?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, bioinformatics

I am dealing with fasta files having lines such as:

```
\>97977-100;sample=Samp1  
TAATGATGATTTGT  
\>97978-60;sample=Samp2  
AACATTCAACGCGGTCGGTGAGTA  
\>97979-30;sample=Samp3  
AACCGTAGGAGTTGATGTGCGGT  
\>97980-20;sample=Samp4  
ACTGTCTGTATGTGGTG
```

I would like to find all characters between `-` and `;` and add them to the end of the line along with the text `;size="(value)";`, so I would get:

```
\>97977-100;sample=Samp1;size=100;  
TAATGATGATTTGT  
\>97978-60;sample=Samp2;size=60;  
AACATTCAACGCGGTCGGTGAGTA  
\>97979-30;sample=Samp3;size=30;  
AACCGTAGGAGTTGATGTGCGGT  
\>97980-20;sample=Samp4;size=20;  
ACTGTCTGTATGTGGTG
```

I have seen on [this Question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273496/how-do-i-display-all-the-characters-between-two-specific-strings) some help on how to find the characters between 2 strings, and I can get them with something like:

```
sed -n 1~2p $file | sed -e 's/.*-\(.*\);.*/\1/'
```

And I know how to append to end of a line with:

```
sed "1~2s/$/;size=(I want this to be the output of the command above);/" $file
```

But I am not getting the two together. Neither `sed` with a command as it gives too large argument error.

Comment: Please take a look at the [editing help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and use code blocks to format the sample input and output

Comment: Ok, thank you @ilkkachu, I have looked and changed something, but I am still not sure how to put the input text (starting with >) and the output text into boxes / chunks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`sed`** solution:

```
sed -E 's/(.*-)([0-9]+)(;.*)/\1\2\3;size=\2;/' file
```

The output:

```
>97977-100;sample=Samp1;size=100;
TAATGATGATTTGT
>97978-60;sample=Samp2;size=60;
AACATTCAACGCGGTCGGTGAGTA
>97979-30;sample=Samp3;size=30;
AACCGTAGGAGTTGATGTGCGGT
>97980-20;sample=Samp4;size=20;
```

---

Or with **`awk`**:

```
awk -F'-' '/^>/{ $0=$0";size=" int($2) ";" }1' file
```

Comment: Fantastic, many thanks @RomanPerekhrest, works great! :)

Comment: @MafaldaGalhardo, you're welcome