# Extract text between two characters (multiline input)

Tags: sed

If I have the text:

```
aaaaaaaaa
#some info
other rows
end row#
another info
```

How could I extract only the text between the characters `#` obtaining only:

```
some info
other rows
end row
```

I was trying with `sed` in this way:

```
echo -e "aaaaaaaaa\n#some info\nother rows\nend row#\nanother info" |
sed -n -e '/\#/,/\#/p'
```

but it gives me also the character `#`. Is there a way to remove `#` using `sed`?

Comment: pipe to `tr -d "#"`, eg. `sed -n '/#/,/#/p' | tr -d "#"`

Comment: The only thing missing in those duplicates would be removing the delimiters (`#` here)

Comment: @JeffSchaller - here's an [answer that does that too](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/273511/22142)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `perl`:

```
echo -e "aaaaaaaaa\n#some info\nother rows\nend row#\nanother info" |\
perl -0777 -ne '/#([^#]*)#/ && print $1,"\n"; '
```

Explanation:

- `-0777` slurp the whole file as one line (enables multiline matching)
- `/#([^#]*)#/` match non-# characters `[^#]` between too `#` and with the brackets add it as first matching group.
- `&& print $1,"\n"` if found, print first matching group and a final newline.

Comment: You could also use a non-greedy quantifier `/#(.*?)#/` and you should probably use `&&` instead of `;` to separate the match and the print -- that will prevent a single newline from being printed if the match is not found.

Comment: I tried with the non-greedy quantifier, but doesn't work. Good idea though with the `&&`.

Comment: That's a very common source of bugs, assuming the RE matches and $1 has s value

Comment: what do you mean with RE? could you make an example? Thanks to all of you!

Comment: RE = regular expression

Comment: "assuming the RE matches and $1 has s value" for example if its call inside an script where $1 is the argument of the script?  do you mean this or ?  thanksss!

Comment: No, that is prevented by the single quotes. He means I should not do `do_something; do_something_dependent;` but rather `do_something && do_something_dependent;`. In this case `print $1` is dependent on the pattern match (`/#([^#]*)#/`). If you don't know what I am talking about, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-a-shell-command).

Answer (score 5):

Slight adaption to your `sed` one liner:

```
echo -e "aaaaaaaaa\n#some info\nother rows\nend row#\nanother info" |
sed -n '/^#/,/#$/ {s/#//;p;}'
```

Output:

```
some info
other rows
end row
```

Comment: thanks, but if the '#' is not the first or last character? In this case sed doesn't work !?