# how to use \n( and )\n as delimiter in awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, gawk

I have a file which contains below data

```
7[label = "ScanStep: T_b0\n(T.a = 1)\na\nb\nc\nd\ne\ndob\ntimestamp1\nUnc: Integer(8)\nUnc: Integer(8)\nUnc: Varchar(80)\nUnc: Numeric(10,2)\nUnc: Varbinary(80)\nUnc: Date(8)\nUnc: Timestamp(8)", color = "brown", shape = "box"];

7[label = "ScanStep: cde_b1\nBuddies: (cde_b1, cde_b0, cde_b2)\n(public.cde.newcol = \'013\')\nssn\nnewcol\nmasked_ssn\nUnc: Numeric(10,2)\nUnc: Varbinary(80)\nUnc: Date(8)\nUnc: Timestamp(8)", color = "brown", shape = "box"];
```

there are multiple such entries.

I need to print only those entries which comes after "\n(" and before ")\n".

I have tried with awk but unable to provide delimiter.

```
awk -F "\\n\\\\(" '{print $1}' unset
```

> prints whole line of the file

```
awk -F "\\n\\(" '{print $1}' unset
```

> prints awk: warning: escape sequence `\(' treated as plain`('
>   awk: fatal: Unmatched ( or (: /
>   (/

Comment: Sounds like a perfect use case for perl's [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) e.g. `grep -Po '(?<=\\n\().*?(?=\)\\n)'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find/grep what is between string1 and string2?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266904/how-to-find-grep-what-is-between-string1-and-string2)

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with `sed` like so:

```
sed -e 's,\\n(.*,,' unset
```

or with `awk` you have to do a lot of escaping

```
awk -F'\\\\n\\(' '{print $1}' unset
```

to get the right escaping for both the `\` before the `n` and to protect against the special interpretation of the `(`

Comment: Thanks Eric. It worked and m using this one as awk is bit fast as compare to sed and other stuffs.

Answer (score 1):

I used a combination of grep and sed to accomplish your goal of after \n( and before )\n

```
grep -o '\\n(.*)\\n' test.txt|sed -e 's/\\n//g'
```

Sample output

```
(T.a = 1)
(public.cde.newcol = \'013\')
```